# R shiny display wellPanel objects horizontally

Tags: r, shiny

I have wellPanel:

```
   wellPanel(
              h5("Accuracy table:"),
              tableOutput(accuracy_tablename))
          )
```

[image]

I want to display objects in wellPanel horizontally. How can I manage that?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a div with the class "row" (or "row-fluid") and insert sub-divs (the "spanX" class specify the space between each divs) which will be displayed horizontally.

```
shiny::runApp(list(
  ui = basicPage(
    wellPanel(
      tags$div(class = "row",
        tags$div(class = "span4",
          h5("Accuracy table:")
        ),
        tags$div(class = "span4",
          tableOutput("table")
        )
      )
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {

    output$table <- renderTable({
      iris[1,]
    })

  }
))
```

Comment: Many thanks for the answer!  I put this into renderUI in server, and it looks like: http://gyazo.com/b3bb8b41a3ef9692bc15b1df5595920b. Text "Accuracy table" doesn't display correctly. Maybe you know, how to correct that?

Comment: Ah yes i think the problem will be solved if you use the "row-fluid" class instead of the "row" one.

Answer (score 3):

In case you mean showing multiple panels side-by-side intead of one-below-the-other, I found the following useful:

```
    div(style="display:inline-block",  
       h5("Accuracy table:"),
       tableOutput(accuracy_tablename))
    )

  div(style="display:inline-block",  
       h5("Accuracy table 2:"),
       tableOutput(accuracy_tablename2))
    )
```

etc.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, that is a good feature and maybe some day I will use it, but today I don't need multiple panels:)